# phpmailer not working in ssl site

Tags: php, phpmailer, ssl

hola tengo un problema con phpmailer, recientemente implemente un certificado ssl en mi sitio, quiero suponer que eso afecta los permisos de escritura y de lectura, pero estoy intentando crear un folder con permisos de escritura y mandar el mail pero no hace ninguna de las dos cosas.

```
<?php
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
require "PHPMailer/PHPMailer.php";
require "PHPMailer/Exception.php";

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] != 'POST') {
header('Location: diplomadoventas.php');
exit();
}

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://ipnpb.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi- 
bin/webscr');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "cmd=_notify-validate&" . 
http_build_query($_POST));
$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

dir = 'myDir';

 // create new directory with 744 permissions if it does not exist yet
 // owner will be the user/group the PHP script is run under
 if ( !file_exists($dir) ) {
 mkdir ($dir, 0744);
 }

 file_put_contents ($dir.'/test.txt', $response);

if($response == "VERIFIED" && $_POST['receiver_email'] == "*********"){
$cEmail = $_POST['payer_email'];
$name = $_POST['first_name'];

$price = $_POST['mc_gross'];
$currency = $_POST['mc_currency'];
$item = $_POST['item_number'];
$paymentStatus = $_POST['payment_status'];

if ($item == "************" && $currency == "USD" $$ $paymentStatus == 
"Completed" && $price == 0.097) {
    $mail = new PHPMailer();

    $mail->setFrom("************", "Sales");
    $mail->addAdress($cEmail, $name);
    $mail->isHTML(true);
    $mail->Subject = "sales";
    $mail->Body = "Hola, <br><br>
    thanks";
  $mail->Port= 465;
  $mail->send();
   }
  }   
?>
```

no esta creando el folder con permisos de escritura.
paypal me manda el handshake veryfied.

Comment: Con qué proveedor de correo estás probando? Se sigue usando SSL en vez de TLS?

Comment: es el ssl gratuito de hostgator. estoy utilizando el simple ssl plugin de wordpress. Se ve bien el código?. el conflicto puede ser con el certificado?

Comment: Debugea en el phpmailer                                                                
`$mail->SMTPDebugSMTP::DEBUG_SERVER;
$mail->SMTPDebug = 2` y a ver qué te dice